# Group data by month and year

Tags: python

I have a .json file containing a lot of articles, each article is formatted like this:

```
{
"source": "....",
"title": ".......",
"original_time": "ora: 20:03, 06 dec 2006",
"datetime": "2006-12-06T20:03:00+00:00",
"views": 398,
"comments": 1,
"content": "..."
"id": "13",
}
```

Now I have to sum up the numbers of views of all articles for each month and year and to plot the results...but I don't know how to do this because I'm new to python...This is what I have done:

```
import json
#from pprint import pprint
import csv
import time
import datetime

views = []
time = []
art_timpul = 0
unimedia = 0
total_articles = 0
json_data=open('all.json')
data = json.load(json_data)
#pprint(data)
json_data.close()

for i in data:
    if i["source"] == 'unimedia':
        art_unimedia += 1
        x = i["views"]
        views.append(int(x))
        y = i["original_time"]
        time.append(y)
    if i["source"] == 'timpul':
        art_timpul += 1
    total_articles += 1

myfile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(views)

print time
#print views
print "Articles from Unimedia", art_unimedia
print "Articles from Timpul", art_timpul        
print "Total articles", total_articles
```

Edit: I have to group data by month and year, I have to sum up the nr of views from articles written in that month and year...and export them into a file

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Extracting the data from json, parsing the date string, grouping the data, ...? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have to group data by month and year, I have to sum up the nr of views from articles written in that month and year...and export them into a file

Comment: you should look into pandas. it's good for this sort of thing, but there's a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear from your question, but I'll assume that you do not have a problem with reading and writing the files, but only with parsing the date string and grouping the data.

First, parsing the date. Here you can use e.g. `dateutil.parser.parse` or [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime). `dateutil.parser` seems to expect a date format just like yours by default, so we'll use this instead of [configuring the format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for `strptime`.

Next, the grouping: Easiest would be to use a number of [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) mapping months or years to views. You could also use a dictionary for different sources, instead of those two variables you have now. Just use the month or year as key to the dictionary and update the value accordingly. To make life a bit easier, we can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), so we don't have to check whether that key already exists.

Example for grouping by month (similar for year and source etc. in the same loop):

```
import collections, dateutil.parser
views_by_month = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in data:
    views = item["views"]
    date = dateutil.parser.parse(item["datetime"])
    views_by_month[date.month] += views
print views_by_month
```

Comment: thanks, I have modified a little bit to work like this : Jan 2006, Feb 2006, Mar 2006...until May 2014...for each month from every year :)